# Android client to Java Server in case plenty of simultaneously connections

Tags: java, android, spring, hibernate, server

I'm going  to develop both client and server trading system applications. 
The client side is Android. Server gets stock quotes from outside source. There is database on the server which holds information about users accounts, users operations. On the server side  Spring Security, Hibernate are used. What the technologies for user authorizing on the server and operation performing (open/close/change positions) should i use  in case plenty of simultaneously connections? 
Please give me some hints, code examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JWT](https://jwt.io) for authentication, it's super easy to understand and use and there are plenty of tutorials online.